# Synergy between Windows XP/7 and Linux Mint 12RC fails

Tags: synergy

Synergy icon shows the two computers are connected, but mouse is not shared. (linux server, windows client).

Anybody has a workaround ?

Comment: Ooops, fixed it. Please ignore/delete the question.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue.  The client (win7) connects but most of the time the cursor never switches screens.

I just discovered that if you run the mouse to the border of the screen with debug on it never says anything about trying to switch to the other screen, so seems like it can't detect the edge of the screen.

I happened to place an xterm on the edge of the screen and I can make the cursor switch to the other screen if it exits off the screen edge where the xterm window is, but if I go to the edge of the screen where there is no app window it doesn't switch.  So maybe the window manager is somehow protecting the screen edges or the edge-events for its own purposes and syngergy server never gets the event that the cursor got to the screen edge if it's on the desktop.  If I hit the screen egde over where an app is running it switches to the other side.

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem as well with Linux Mint 12 running Cinnamon.

I have found out that if I have chromium open, it detects the edge of the screen and lets me switch. You just can't switch from the main desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why it should not work since I am using pretty much the same set-up. Try running both `synergyc` and `synergys` with `--no-daemon` option and add necessary `--debug` options to see if the client and server are connected correctly. Seeing an icon means nothing.

From Synergy man page:

```
-d, --debug <level>
    filter out log messages with priority below level.
    level may be: FATAL, ERROR, WARNING, NOTE,
                  INFO, DEBUG, DEBUGn (1-5).
```